# How do I close the Games or Camera apps on Nokia Lumia 535?

Tags: games, nokia-lumia-535, lumia-denim

The Lumia 535 doesn't have a physical Back button, and the virtual button bar doesn't appear when I'm in the Games or Camera apps. How do I close them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to show the virtual button bar in Windows Phone 8.1, simply swipe up from the bottom of the display.